# How to encode a series of integer boolean pairs?

Tags: postgresql, encoding, compression, embedding

I have a series of integers 1,2,3,...,22. That are paired with a boolean (there is no pattern).
The integers and booleans get a column each in a db table with every new item being a row.
All these rows belong to one instance of a foreign key (The numbers will cycle from 1 to 22 for every different key).

Example Input (This is for one key);

```
+--------+------+
| number | bool |
+--------+------+
|      1 |    0 |
|      2 |    0 |
|      3 |    1 |
|    ... |  ... |
|     22 |    1 |
+--------+------+
```

Is there any such compression technique where I can collapse all those rows down to a single row?

Obviously, a sum of pairwise products won't work as [(9,1)] is equivalent to [(3,1),(6,1)].

I don't know compression algorithms well enough to develop a rock-solid solution. Thus I am fully prepared for the possibility of some very famous algorithm already existing and me not being aware of it.

However!

Since the numbers just cycle, why not store the booleans as a 22-bit integer where the n-th number corresponds to the n-th bit in the binary? It won't save space that much (perhaps by half?), but it will make queries much easier. And a dictionary/lookup or something to decompress when required (22 bits is a lot. But nothing that can't be decompressed ad-hoc?)?

Not sure if I am overlooking something.

Example Output (Of my idea, doesn't need to be this way);

```
+--------+------+
| fkey   | cmp  |
+--------+------+
|      1 |..010 |
|      2 |..110 |
|      3 |..001 |
+--------+------+
```

I suppose my question is can it be done in less than 22 bits per key? And what are the tradeoffs?

Comment: You can rearrange the data (a 32 bit int, or bit strong)  but there are always trade offs. What are you representing? Start with that and only complicate your life if your measurements show a real performance issue.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how it will change performance (it might make it worse since the ORM will have to run the "decompress" algorithm instead of just querying the table). However it will make querying the dataset (with sql) much simpler given that now one unique foreign key will have one row instead of 22 rows.

Answer (score 0):

See example. There `number` is `bool` type - 1 byte and casted to int.
bit_or (bitwise sum) is also return integer value.

```
create table test(id int,pk int,num int,bval bool);
insert into test values
 (1,100,1 , false )
,(2,100,2 , false )
,(3,100,3 , true )
,(4,100,22, true )
,(5,101,4, true )
,(6,102,1, true )
;
```

Query with compressing

```
select pk
  ,bit_or(cast(bval as int)<<(num-1)) ts
  ,to_hex(bit_or(cast(bval as int)<<(num-1))) hexv
from test
group by pk
```

Output

| pk | ts | hexv |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 2097156 | 200004 |
| 101 | 8 | 8 |
| 102 | 1 | 1 |